# Understanding a subsequence converges in the proof of completeness of $L^p$ in Stein-Shakarchi's Functional Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces

I am trying to understand the following proof of completeness of $L^p$ in [Stein-Shakarchi's Functional Analysis](http://assets.press.princeton.edu/chapters/s9627.pdf). (See the proof on page 5 of the link or at the end of this post.)

In the proof, it is said that:

> Since
>   (by construction of the telescopic series) the $(K − 1)^{\mathrm{th}}$ partial sum of
>   this series is precisely $f_{n_K}$ , we find that $f_{n_K}\to f$ a.e.

**Question 1**: why is this true?

What I tried is $f(x)=f_{n_1}(x)+f_{n_{K+1}}-f_{n_1}(x)+(f_{n_{K+2}}+f_{n_{K+3}}+...)=f_{n_{K+1}}+(f_{n_{K+2}}+f_{n_{K+3}}+...)$

If $K\to\infty$ is it correct to conclude $f_{n_K}\to f$ ?

**Question 2**: why $2^p|f(x)|^p+2^p|S_K(f)(x)|^p\le2^{p+1}|g(x)|^p,$ for all $K$ ?

---

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Which book is the excerpt from? Stein-Shakarchi?

Comment: @Jack from this page 5 http://assets.press.princeton.edu/chapters/s9627.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Theorem 1.3 in Section 1.2 (page 5) of Stein-Shakarchi's Functional Analysis.

Note that

- the $(K-1)^{\mathrm{th}}$ partial sum in the proof refers to $S_K(f)(x)$, which by the definition formula *equals* to $f_{n_K}$;
- by the proof, $S_K(f)\to f$ almost everywhere.

Thus the authors conclude that $f_{n_K}=S_{K-1}(f)\to f$ almost everywhere.

For the second question, simply note that by the triangle inequality,
$$
|f(x)|\leq |g(x)|,\quad |S_K(f)|\leq |g(x)|.
$$

Comment: - by the proof, $S_K(f)\to f$ a.e. what proof are you citing ?

Comment: The proof in Stein-Shakarchi: "... hence the series defining $f$ converges almost everywhere, and $f\in L^p$".

Comment: though it is $_{_}=_{−1}()$ without the last term $K$, even still it holds $_{_}→ $ ?

Comment: @galleta For any convergent sequence of complex numbers $(z_k)$, $\lim_{k\to\infty}z_{k}=\lim_{k\to\infty}z_{k-1}$.

Comment: Now makes sense, Thank you for your help Jack